# Xcode missing constraint warning for y position but it's set

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, uistoryboard

I have in the same view controller two `UITableView`. Both `UITableView` cells have an `UIImageView`, a top `UILabel`  with top and lead constraints, a bottom `UILabel` with lead and bottom constraint. Cells are set the same for constraints but on the second `UITableView` cell Xcode gives me a missing constraint warning for y position on bottom `UILabel` , when it actually has a bottom constraint. If I add a top constraint for the bottom label in the second `UITableView` cell the warning goes away, but it's not needed for the first `UITableView`. What am I doing wrong?
As always many thanks.

[image: correct] [image: warning]

Comment: Hi, don't use leading and traling please use alignment Y For All element

Comment: @YogeshPatel do you mean inside a stack?

Comment: No constrain alignment Y in before size class in Xcode storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `Storyboard` at this case maybe will be better embed your labels at `Stack View`? And this will make your Cell more changeable and you should better to maintain it?

[image]

Comment: thank you.  I rather stay away from stacks.. never got to understand how to use them properly.. I want to have the label on the left taking whatever space is left between the label on the right and the end of the `ContentView`.. that's what I just set 2 constraints..
it's just weird that in the same constraint set up I get two different results..

Comment: If your cells are identically you can create .xib for this cell, give for it identifier and setup information from your model at rendering this cell at `cellForRow`.

Comment: Also, you can read detail about UIStackView and how it to use at https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/stack-views.html and https://www.raywenderlich.com/508-uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: Thank you for the links. I really think it's time to master them .

Comment: I finally got a grip on stack views. There is only on thing that I can't yet set as I want to. Basically the whole set up is:
1. An horizontal stack, set as fill proportionally,  with inside the `imageView` and another horizontal stack view .
2. In the second horizontal stack, also set as fill proportionally, view I have two vertical stack views, set as Equal spacing with two labels in each one. 

The spacing value I specify dough gets distributed only between the two tables in the stack view, so labels are always stuck to top and bottom of the stack view..how to add in padding?

Comment: Found it. Layout margins.